# How to properly avoid if-expressions by using vector indices?

Tags: r, vector

x is a vector of integers ranging between 1 and 100

I created a function that determines in which category a number is:

```
x∈[1,20]: small
x∈[21,50]: med 
x∈[51, 100]:large
```

Here the function:

```
x <- c(1:99)

vector.fun<-function(x){
  x[x >= 1 & x <=20] <-"small"
  x[x >= 21 & x <=50] <-"med" 
  x[x >=51 & x <=99] <-"large"
  return(x)
}
vector.fun(89)
```

However as you can see, in the function my vector is 1:99 instead of 1:100, for some reason when i change it to:

```
x <- c(1:100)

    vector.fun<-function(x){
      x[x >= 1 & x <=20] <-"small"
      x[x >= 21 & x <=50] <-"med" 
      x[x >=51 & x <=100] <-"large"
      return(x)
    }
    vector.fun(100)
```

it doesn't recognise any number from the last line: `x[x >=51 & x <=100] <-"large"` and when it does it returns "med" instead of "large" as it should be.

what am I doing wrong? Which changes should I do in my function in order that 100 is included in the parameter and returns "large"?

Comment: `coercion` is a likely culprit

Comment: Your function parameter is the same as your original vector. The vector outside the function is never used.

Comment: The first time you replace indices in your `x` with "small", `x` is coerced to "character" and you end with comparisons like `c("1", "50", "60") >= "51"` and `c("1", "50", "60") <= "100"`  which might differ from their "numeric" equivalents. Instead, for such problems, use `cut(x, c(0, 20, 50, 100), labels = c("small", "med", "large"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a coercion problem as mentioned in the comments above.
If you want to keep your function structure the way you created it, you can alter it as follows:

```
vector.fun<-function(y){
    x <- y
    x[y >= 1 & y <=20] <-"small"
    x[y >= 21 & y <=50] <-"med" 
    x[y >=51 & y <=100] <-"large"
    return(x)
}
```

Although the solution suggested by @alexis_laz is more concise and elegant:

```
vector.fun<-function(x){
   cut(x, c(0,20,50,100), labels = c("small", "med", "large"))
}
```

Keep in mind, this second version will produce a *factor* type vector, while the first version will produce a *character* type vector.

Comment: Thanks:P makes sense now.